# Why does Firestore send all results, instead of just the new items when using on_snapshot?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase's Firestore to store and publish new events.

In the code below, I'm subscribing to a collection and want to be notified when a new items is added (this code is executing on a browser).

When I first connect, I would like to receive a true *snapshot*. However, once I'm connected to Firestore and have received an initial snapshot, with each new item, I only want to get the udpates, not the whole collection over and over again!

```js
function queryExercise(exercise){
    db.collection("exercises").where("exercise","==",exercise).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            var d_ = doc.data()
            console.log(d_);
            ...do somethign with d_...
        })
    })    
}
```

When I publish a new item to the collection, my console is full of *all* events received earlier...in other words, it is sending me the full snapshot, instead of just the deltas.

Am I doing something wrong or does the API really not support delta updates?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way Firestore queries work.  If you don't provide a filter for which documents you want in a collection, you will get all the documents in that collection.  The only way to change this behavior is to provide a [filter](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) in your query using a where clause.

It sounds like you have a thought in mind about what makes for a "new" document in your collection.  You will need to represent that using some field in the documents in your collection.  Usually this will be a timestamp type field that's added or modified whenever a document is created or changed. This will be part of your where clause that determines what's "new". Use this field as a filter to find out what's new.

Comment: I think OP is not worried about getting all documents on the first query snapshot, but on all subsequent snapshot. In that case @Shahbaz's answer is probably what they're looking for (hence I upvoted that one).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to read on docChanges:

```js
function queryExercise(exercise){
    db.collection("exercises").where("exercise","==",exercise).onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
        //              \/-----this thing
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change){
            var d_ = change.doc.data()
            console.log("Change type:", change.type, d_);
            ...
        });
    })    
}
```

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen